# Custom plugin wp

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, plugin

Tengo el siguiente codigo

```
function app_searched_today_visitbh() {
    global $wpdb;
    $horas = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT time_format(timediff(now(),date_people),'%i%h') FROM today_people LIMIT 1"); 
    return ("<span id='days_since'>$horas</span>");
}

add_shortcode('appsearchedtodayvisitbh', 'app_searched_today_visitbh');
```

Su funcionamiento es el siguiente, agrega el resultado de DATE en un `span` consultando la base de datos, en una tabla `today_people` con un columna `date_people` de formato DATETIME,

---

ACTUALIZACION

Este codigo es un poco viejo, lo que realmente necesito, es que sea como un contador de visitas pero manual, que yo deje el numero 5, y el comience cada minuto a aumentar. Sin necesidad de cookies o localstorage.

Muchas gracias! espero su ayuda!

Comment: Creo que no te has explicado del todo bien. ¿De dónde quieres que salgan los números consecutivos? ¿Dónde se muestra el número consecutivo, en el `span`? ¿Aparte de que se muestre la `$hora` recogida de la BD, quieres que se muestren números consecutivos? Explica mejor tu pregunta, y muéstranos un ejemplo del resultado que querrías obtener, más detalladamente

Comment: @cnbandicoot Muchas gracias, voy a mejorar la pregunta

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo que lo que quieres es sacar de las horas, los días. Tengo un código en PHP que dada la diferencia en milisegundos, te saca las horas, minutos y segundos.

```
public function humanTime($milisegundos)
{
    $horas = (int) (($milisegundos / (1000*60*60)) % 24);
    $minutos = (int) (($milisegundos / (1000*60)) % 60);
    $segundos = (float) (($milisegundos % (1000*60*60)) % (1000*60)) / 1000;
    $tiempo ='';

    if ($horas > 0) {
        $tiempo = "{$tiempo}{$horas} h";
    }

    if ($minutos > 0) {
        $tiempo = "{$tiempo} {$minutos} min";
    }

    if ($segundos > 0) {
        $tiempo = "{$tiempo} {$segundos} seg";
    }

    return $tiempo;
}
```

Modificandolo un poco, puedes sacar los días, horas, minutos y segundos, que entiendo que es lo que quieres.

Si es así dime, y se puede modificar para ello.

Comment: Super, @sakrow mi codigo es un poco viejo, lo que realmente necesito, es que sea como un contador de visitas pero manual, que yo deje el numero 5, y el comience cada minuto a aumentar. Sin necesidad de cookies o localstorage.

Comment: ejemplo [https://www.cerotec.net/contador.php?t=4&s=2&i=94708]